# Choose a drive letter using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, drive

I'm trying to create a gui using tkinter which allows for a user to select a drive letter and have the gui end and return the drive letter selected. I'm having trouble finding the correct way to have a user select from a list of drives and return the drive. If someone could help that would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is what you need [Filedialog](https://pythonspot.com/tk-file-dialogs/)

Answer (score 1):

Assume you are in Windows platform, you can use `win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()` to get the available drives.  Below is a sample program:

```
import win32api
from tkinter import *

def select_drive(drv):
    # print the drive and then exit program
    print(drv)
    root.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.title('Select Drive')

drives = [x[:2] for x in win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split('\x00')[:-1]]
font=('Courier New', 14, 'bold')
for i, drv in enumerate(drives):
    Button(text=drv, font=font, width=5, command=lambda d=drv: select_drive(d)).grid(row=i//5, column=i%5, padx=5, pady=3)

root.mainloop()
```

And the output:

[image]

***Updated:** if you do not have **`win32api`** module installed, you can use the following code to get the available drives:*

```
import os, string

drives = ['%s:'%d for d in string.ascii_uppercase if os.path.exists('%s:'%d)]
```